# Error while running the Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created a very simple Spring Boot application(Dog Rescue application) that stores the dog information , and i am getting the error while executing the application

> Error Info
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
> Request method 'GET' not supported

My index.html file is

```
<h2>Add A Dog</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/home}">
    <label>Name<input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input></label>
    <label>Vaccinated<input type="text" name="vaccinated" id="vaccinated"></input></label>
    <label>Rescued<input type="text" name="rescued" id="rescued"></input></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller File is

```
package com.dog.resue.controller;

import com.dog.resue.dao.DodRepository;
import com.dog.resue.service.DogService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Date;

@Controller
public class DogController {

    @Autowired
    private DodRepository dodRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DogService dogService;

    @PostMapping(value ="/home")
    public String adddog(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                          @RequestParam("rescued") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date rescued,
                          @RequestParam("vaccinated") Boolean vaccinated, Model model)
    {
        dogService.addADog(name, rescued, vaccinated);
        System.out.println("name = " + name + ",rescued = " + rescued + ", vaccinated = " + vaccinated);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

    }
```

The complete project is available [here](https://github.com/arulsuju/DogRescue.git)

Comment: change @PostMapping(value ="/home") to @GetMapping(value ="/home") or change in htmp from GET to POST

Comment: I am getting the following error There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'name' is not present

Answer (score 0):

`<form .. method="post">` should fix it.

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: did you try by putting method="post" in <form> tag?